# How is this circle in $S^1 \times D^2$ null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This picture is from Hatcher's AT:

[image]

I have been told that this circle is null-homotopic, but I can't see why. I know $S^1 \times D^2$ is a solid torus, but $A$ is linked with itself. How are we to unwind $A$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A$ is allowed to cross itself in the homotopy.

For example, "homotopic to a point" means that at the end, all of $A$ is at a single point (which is obviously not injective).

If you believe that $\pi_1(\mathbf R^3) = \{e\}$ then you believe that every knot in $\mathbf R^3$ is null-homotopic. This is the same thing.

This is also why knots [are not defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) up to "homotopy" but rather a different relation called "ambient isotopy."

Comment: Why/How is $A$ allowed to cross itself during the homotopy?

Comment: @AlJebr There's no rule that says that it can't. You need to allow paths to cross if you want to consider the constant map as a path.

Comment: @AlJebr, you may be confusing "homotopy" with "isotopy."

Comment: @TrevorGunn Is a space crossing itself during a homotopy a continuous function?